# C pointer and dynamic alloc

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I'm studying the C language for just 2 weeks now and I'm facing problems with the dynamic allocs and the pointers, I'm a little bit confused about the following code.

I try to understand how the read function work but the `*m` confuse me. I just can't find a way to use the `*m` parametre, also the

```
if((*h = (struct inhabitant *)malloc(sizeof(struct inhabitant) * (*m))) == NULL)
```

I'm just blown away.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "inhabitants.h"
#include "sort.h"

void read(FILE *s, struct inhabitant **h, int *m) {
  int i, ntok;
  struct inhabitant *tmph;

  ntok = fscanf(s, "%d", m);
  if(ntok != 1 || *m < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to read file.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  if((*h = (struct inhabitant *)malloc(sizeof(struct inhabitant) * (*m))) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate space for inhabitants.\n");
    exit(-1);
  }

  tmph = *h;
  for(i = 0; i < (*m); ++i) {
    ntok = fscanf(s, "%d %s %s %d", &(tmph[i].distance), (char *)&(tmph[i].prenom), (char *)&(tmph[i].nom), (int *)&(tmph[i].zip));
    if(ntok != 4) {
      fprintf(stderr, "File wrongly formatted.\n");
      exit(-1);
    }
  }

}

int compare_inhabitants_by_distance(struct inhabitant *a, struct inhabitant *b) {
    if (a->distance > b->distance)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
  //à compléter
}

int compare_inhabitants_by_zipcode(struct inhabitant *a, struct inhabitant *b) {
  if (a->enum zipcode > b->enum zipcode)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
  //à compléter
}

void show(int n, struct inhabitant *a) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    printf("%d, %s, %s, %d\n", a[i].distance, a[i].prenom, a[i].nom, a[i].zip);
  }
}

void printout(FILE *s, int n, struct inhabitant *a) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    fprintf(s, "%d %s %s %d\n", a[i].distance, a[i].prenom, a[i].nom, a[i].zip);
  }
}

#define PERSONS_TO_SAVE_FILE_IN "evacuation_plan0.txt"
#define PERSONS_TO_SAVE_FILE_OUT "better_evacuation_plan0.txt"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  FILE *s;
  int n;
  /*For testing purpose :
  struct inhabitant inhabs[] = {
                                { 100, "Jean", "France", GUADELOUPE },
                                { 10, "Ameni", "Braminia", STBARTH },
                                { 12, "Mathieu", "Krister", GUADELOUPE },
                                { 23, "Hilaire  ", "Blanchi", STMARTIN }
                              };
  n = sizeof(inhabs) / sizeof(*inhabs);*/

  struct inhabitant *inhabs0;


  if((s = fopen(PERSONS_TO_SAVE_FILE_IN, "r")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file.");
    exit(-1);
  }

  read(s, inhabs, )

  /*
  A compléter :
  - Lecture du fichier.
  - Tris.
  */

  if((s = fopen(PERSONS_TO_SAVE_FILE_OUT, "w+")) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to open file.");
    exit(-1);
  }
  printout(s, n, inhabs0);
  fclose(s);

  free(inhabs0);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Your code is not an [MCVE].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, an [assignment](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_assignment) is some [expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions), and expressions are a simple (and very common) kind of [statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/statements).

So instead of

```
int a = 2+3;
if (a>4) {
```

you might code

```
int a;
if ((a=2+3) > 4) {
```

which has the same [semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics_(computer_science)).

So your [`if` statement](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/if) is similar to:

```
*h = (struct inhabitant *)malloc(sizeof(struct inhabitant) * (*m));
if (*h == NULL)
```

<sup>(using a complex `if` like in the original code, or splitting it into two statements, is a matter of readability and taste; however, be aware of [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point))</sup>

BTW, what follows in the original code is poor taste (and using [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) with -1 is also poor taste). You'll better use [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html) or [strerror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) with [errno(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html) to explain why `malloc`  failed. So I recommend then

```
  { // when *h is NULL because malloc failed
     fprintf(stderr, 
             "Unable to allocate space for %d inhabitants: %s\n", 
             *m, strerror(errno));
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
```

and in your particular case (allocating an array) I would recommend using [calloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3.html) (to get some zero-initialized memory zone) instead of `malloc`.

BTW, I recommend changing the name of your `read`  function. It can be confused with POSIX [read](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html).

Don't forget to compile with all warnings and debug info, so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (read about [Invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html)). Improve your code to get no warnings. Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every function before using it. Learn to [use the debugger `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/). Work hard to avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), and be very [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of them.

Read also more about [C dynamic memory allocation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation), [pointer aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_aliasing), [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space), [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), [garbage collection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)), [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). In addition of the `gdb` debugger, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) is sometimes useful too. Study also the source code of *existing* [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)), you'll learn a lot.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the other error pointed out, your `fscanf` variables are wrong. You do no need to pass the *address of* `prenum` or `nom` as they are already pointers, e.g.

```
    for (i = 0; i < *m; ++i) {
        /* casts should not be necessary, prenom & nom already pointers */
        ntok = fscanf (s, "%d %s %s %d", &tmph[i].distance, (tmph[i].prenom),
                        (tmph[i].nom), &(tmph[i].zip));
```

Further, the allocation itself is somewhat clumsy. Use the variable name instead of the type for `sizeof` and there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, e.g.

```
    /* allocate/validate space for 'm' inhabitants */
    if ((*h = malloc (sizeof **h * *m)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to allocate space for inhabitants.\n");
        exit (-1);
    }
```

See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Putting it altogether, your read function could be updated to something similar to:

```
void read (FILE *s, struct inhabitant **h, int *m)
{
    int i, ntok;
    struct inhabitant *tmph;

    ntok = fscanf (s, "%d", m);
    if (ntok != 1 || *m < 0) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to read file.\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    /* allocate/validate space for 'm' inhabitants */
    if ((*h = malloc (sizeof **h * *m)) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Unable to allocate space for inhabitants.\n");
        exit (-1);
    }

    tmph = *h;
    for (i = 0; i < *m; ++i) {
        /* casts should not be necessary, prenom & nom already pointers */
        ntok = fscanf (s, "%d %s %s %d", &tmph[i].distance, (tmph[i].prenom),
                        (tmph[i].nom), &(tmph[i].zip));
        if (ntok != 4) {
            fprintf (stderr, "File wrongly formatted.\n");
            exit (-1);
        }
    }
}
```

**note:** you also have an apparent typo here in `main()`, `read(s, inhabs, )` appears intended as `read (s, &inhabs0);` If you give `read` a meaningful return type, like perhaps `int`, then you could return `0` or `1` to indicate success/failure without automatically exiting your program from within the function.